# Bind variable to object property

Tags: javascript

I am changing a global variable to the value of the input field in the HTML. I am then trying to take this value and use it inside another variable. However, this does not work, in console the value changes but not inside the variable opts. How do I make javascript pass this information successfully? Here is a link to jsfiddle where I have it running. I am trying to change the number of rays in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/9vdpt81n/

```
var loadValue = 1;

function val() {
    newValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
    loadValue = newValue;
}
val(opts);

var opts = {
        rays: loadValue,
        radiantSpan: loadValue,
}
```

Comment: There's no way to "bind" an object property to a variable like that.

Comment: Please turn this code into a runnable snippet, including the `console.log` so we can run it and see what you mean.

Comment: Also note that you're sending an argument to the `val()` function but it doesn't expect one.

Comment: Why do you call `val` with an argument when your function takes none?

Comment: I have added a link to jsfiddle in the question. @trincot

Comment: Why do you have two properties with the same value. Can you explain if you ever have a case where the current values of these properties would be different from eachother?

Comment: @trincot please check the full example on: https://jsfiddle.net/9vdpt81n/

Comment: I checked, but you should really provide a minimal example, not full blown code with all kinds of stuff that is not related to the question. Could you please make a short piece of runnable code that demonstrates the issue, and also answer my last question? (Yes/No)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) which binds a function to an Object property and uses the return value of that function each time the property is looked up.

```
var opts = {
    get rays(){
       return loadValue;
    },
    get radiantSpan(){
       return loadValue;
   }
}
```

```js
var loadValue = 1;
var opts = {
    get rays(){
       return loadValue;
    },
    get radiantSpan(){
       return loadValue;
   }
}
function showOpts(){
console.log('opts.rays:', opts.rays);
console.log('opts.radiantSpan:', opts.radiantSpan);
} 
showOpts();
loadValue++;
showOpts();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/af0mnywL/

Alternatively, you could set the value of the rays and radiantSpan properties of your object on the change event of the input.

```
function val() {
    var newValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
    loadValue = newValue;
    opts.rays = opts.radiantSpan = loadValue;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hwfap3j/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried this, but it does not work I get an Unexpected identifier. Please could you check the full code at: https://jsfiddle.net/9vdpt81n/

Comment: really, great news its been hours I have been trying to work this out, could you please update the code on jsfiddle? would be so much help hev1. :)